# zsh: command not found postgres

Tags: ruby, postgresql, macos, zsh

mac bigSur 11.6.4,
zsh

Issue: I am trying to start postgres server via command "postgres". I am getting the following error "zsh command not found postres"

I installed postgres@12 via homebrew. I see postgresql@12 in /usr/local/var/

The only things in /usr/local/var are: homebrew, log, and postgresql@12

My .zshrc file looks like this as it stands

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
source /usr/local/opt/chruby/share/chruby/chruby.sh
source /usr/local/opt/chruby/share/chruby/auto.sh
export PGDATA=/usr/local/var/postgresql@12
export PGHOST=/tmp
```

Does anyone know if I am missing something?

Comment: The error has `postress` and the command is `postgres` so if the error message was copied correctly that would be the problem. You probably should take a look at [Postgres Homebrew](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Homebrew).

Comment: Oh that was my typo whoops. Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use homebrew's `services` command.

This will list available services (in case you have multiple postgres versions installed) and their statuses:

```
brew services
```

To start a service, run this command:

```
brew services start postgresql@12
```